# Improve a POC of linear regression with sklearn and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Basically, I'm deploying a proof of concept on a linear regression model to validate the accuracy coefficient percentage based on a specific dataset.  To a high-level previous build my model I apply a kind of manipulation in my dataset to ensure that all columns required as input are numeric and OK.

A dataset overview discloses that all columns are numeric and right formatted.
**Predictors:**

[image]

**Target:**

[image]

I run a describe to get more details and validate values once again. (red predictor and yellow target)

[image]

**Deploy model:**

```
# split training and test
X_train, X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split (X,y,test_size=0.80,random_state = 33)

# Apply the scaler
scalerX = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
scalery = StandardScaler().fit(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
X_train = scalerX.transform(X_train)
y_train = scalery.transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))

# split the tragets in training/test
X_test = scalerX.transform(X_test)
y_test = scalery.transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1))

# Create model linear regression
clf_sgd = linear_model.SGDRegressor(loss='squared_loss',penalty=None,random_state=33)
#clf_sgd = LinearRegression()

# Learning based in the model
clf_sgd.fit(X_train,y_train.ravel())
print("Coefficient de determination:",clf_sgd.score(X_train,y_train))
# Model performance
y_pred = clf_sgd.predict(X_test)
print("Coefficient de determination:{0:.3f}".format(metrics.r2_score(y_test,y_pred)))
```

Unfortunately, my results highly suck, are terrible and awful.

[image]

I look forward to listening and gather ideas about how to improve my model, I'm  nooby without too much experience in this domain. thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you can improve:

1) You need to configure the hyper-parameters of your linear model properly. The scikit-learn [SGDRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html) is very sensitive to the choice of values for several parameters, being the most important ones `alpha`, `penalty`, `loss` and `max_iter`. Have a look around and try to learn about a technique called **cross-validation**, and use it to determine sensible values for these parameters given your data.

2) Except in very specific cases, you don't really need to scale the target variable `y`